# How to create animated rollover arrow animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I want to make a rollover button like https://www.plantflags.com/en/

This websites buttons rollover effect.  Example: if you rollover on button then the text should fade-out and an Arrow should come from the left and create. After the roll-out, the arrow goes to right side and fades-out and the text fades-in again.

Example: if you go to that website and roll-over that button, you'll understand.

[image: if you go to that website and roll-over this button then you can understand]

I've studied their code, the `CSS` I can understand but there are is a JS issue which I can't understand.

Can you figure out how I can make it like this type of rollover effect.

There html code like

```
<a href="#" class="promo__button" data-module="modules/AnimatedArrowButton" data-contact-button>Tell me more</a>
```

there data attribute  `modules/AnimatedArrowButton` actually call js and create more span

Demo without effect https://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/78pshojd/

Comment: Based on inspecting their JS the animation appears to be done with TweenLite. It's pretty slick. https://greensock.com/tweenlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my first pass. I tried to keep extra markup to a minimum; the only addition is a span wrapping the text. Arrow is created via [pseudo elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp). It's purely decorative and wouldn't be semantic if constructed out of other elements, in my opinion.

```
<a href="#" class="promo__button">
  <span>Tell me more</span>
</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ewvbq75/

I tried my best to keep the code clean and commented. A few important bits:

1. You'll notice that part of the animation plays on page load. It's a known issue, what you could do is apply the animation class on hover. This looks just as good but avoids the awkward animation of these buttons on page load: https://jsfiddle.net/b5sc9xrp/
2. All of the animations are stored in keyframes at the end. `on hover` or `on mouse over` animation is applied with assignment to, for example `.button:hover span` directive. `on mouse out` is assigned within the standard declaration `.button span` which is a little counter-intuitive and thus worth mentioning. There is no `:un-hover` after all.
3. `forwards` keyword in animation assignment means that the animation will only play forward and stop there. This is key. For example, when we slide the text to the right and fade it out we want it to stay on the last keyframe. Without `forwards` the animation would jump back to keyframe 1.
4. I made the arrow elements 2 pixels in width. I think it looks better and less jumpy than the 1px version but it's an easy enough adjustment.

Let me know if you have any other questions. This was a fun little demo to build.

Comment: wow. great. i am also trying . same effect like example , erasing type . if you see that site then you can understand what i mean.  that arrow animation very smooth .. lets try together... anyway thanks for your great support

Comment: you're very welcome, note that my solution is only using css, no js / jquery required

Answer (score 5):

You can mix css and jQuery to achieve this effect (since you tagged your question with jQuery).

```js
var timeout = null;
var transitionEnd = true;

jQuery('.line').on("mouseenter", function() {
  if (!transitionEnd)
    return;

  _this = jQuery(this);

  _this.addClass("hide-text");

  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    _this.addClass("in");
  }, 300);

  transitionEnd = false;
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);

  jQuery(this).addClass("out").one("transitionend", function() {
    transitionEnd = true;
    jQuery(this).removeClass("hide-text out in");
  });


});
```

```css
.line {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  margin: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
.line::after {
  content: " ";
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  left: -150%;
  transition: left 0.5s, right 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.line::before {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  content: " ";
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.2);
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  width: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.line span,
.line.out span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.line.hide-text span {
  opacity: 0;
}
.line.in::after {
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  opacity: 1;
}
.line.in::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.line.out::before {
  right: -100%;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.line.out::after {
  left: 100%;
  right: -150%;
  transition: left 0.3s, right 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='line'>
  <span class='text'>Button Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: cool.. nice thank for your support. but i think if this will work anchor tag then will be more nice so then can use anywhere where have anchor

Answer (score 3):

I'm positive the button doesn't require javascript.

Here's the high level framework in just html and css:
https://jsfiddle.net/gsvcaLrt/1/

```css
button {
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.arrow {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-30px);
  transition: 0.4s;
}
button:hover .arrow {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.4s;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* hide button on hover */
button:hover .text {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(30px);
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="arrow">--></span>
  <span class="text">Hello</span>
</button>
```

You can add more detail to the different parts of animation sequence with css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution, I suggest using just css `transition`, with the exception of changing one class with javascript to have a different animation for fading in and out.

Take the following structure:

```
<a class="promo__button exit">
  <span class="arrowleft">
     <span>*the arrow that comes from the left*</span>
  </span>
  <span class="message">
     <span>*the text*</span>
  </span>
  <span class="arrowleft">
     <span>*the arrow that disappears to the right*</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

then in css you can have these 6 selectors:

```
.promo__button .message span {
  //the css for the text when it is visible
}

.promo__button:hover .message span {
  //the aditional css for the text when it is faded out
}

.promo__button .arrowleft span {
  //the css for the arrow before it came in from the left (invisible)
}

.promo__button:hover .arrowleft span {
  //the aditional css to make the arrow visible 
}

.promo__button .arrowright span {
  //the css for the arrow after it went away to the right side
}

.promo__button:hover .arrowright span {
  //the aditional css to make the arrow visible 
}
```

now add `.promo__button * * { transition: left 0.2s, opacity, 0.2s}` for all the values that changed from normal to hover

use two classes to hide the unwanted arrow animation:

```
.promo__button.enter .arrowright {display:none}
.promo__button.exit .arrowleft {display:none}
```

and use javascript to switch enter/exit onmouseenter

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but it might be interesting. I have used css only animation with after & before pseudo classes much used.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.promo {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.promo__button {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: .025em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #E21710;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  
}

.promo__button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}

.text {
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-300%, -50%);
  width: 80px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #E21710;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}

.arrow:after,
.arrow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #E21710;
  z-index: 2;
}

.arrow:after {
  top: 7px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.arrow:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -7px;
}

.promo__button:hover .text {
  transform: translateX(200%);
}

.promo__button:hover .arrow {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.promo__button:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 0 37px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02); 
}
.promo__button:hover:after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="promo">
  <a href="#" class="promo__button" data-module="modules/AnimatedArrowButton" data-contact-button>
   <span class="text">Tell me more</span>
   <span class="arrow"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

.